# How can I write this simple Java 8 line of code into Java 7

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-6

I'm trying to implement a CSRF token, but all the info is programmed with Java 8+ version, so what I need is some help rewriting this line in Java 6/7:

`tokenCookie = Arrays.stream(httpReq.getCookies()).filter(c -> c.getName().equals(csrfCookieExpectedName)).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Actually from that line I'm only getting the error in:

`c -> c.getName().equals(csrfCookieExpectedName)`

Comment: Hello and welcome. Considering that it'd basically translate to a loop with an if, have you at least tried on your own before asking here? Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why do you ask for “Java 7” in the title but tag the question with `java-6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @GIO's answer, you could try for-each loop like this:

```
public Cookie getExpectedCookieName(Cookie[] cookies) {
    for (Cookie c : cookies) {
        if (c.getName().equals(csrfCookiesExpectedName)) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call it like this :
`tokenCookie = getExpectedCookieName(httpReq.getCookies());`

Comment: Well I can't return `c`, it's a cookie not a String, I supose I'll have to do `public Cookie getExpectedCookieName`, and also `tokenCookie = getExpectedCookieName(httpReq.getCookies(), csrfCookieExpectedName);`, but thank I will upvote you

Comment: You are right, but i tried to stay as close as possible to your stream, which return ```Optional<Cookie>```, to fix this you could return ```c.getName()``` instead. You could also use code without putting it in a method.

Comment: @jacouille the original code one-liner returns a `Cookie` (because of that final `orElse(null)`), not an `Optional`. My edit should have fixed that by the way.

Answer (score -1):

This is can be converted using a pretty simple for loop. What you need is basically to check every single element of the array, find the first matching element that you need an exit from the loop, if no element matches then simply return null;

```
public Cookie getExpectedCookieName() {

   for (int i = 0; i < httpReq.getCookies().length; i++) {
       if(httpReq.getCookies()[i].getName().equals(csrfCookiesExpectedName)) {
           return httpReq.getCookies()[i];
       }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: And with that function you made how my code would look like?

Comment: lets *hope*  that `getCookies()` is not expensive